# MongoDB - aggregation - $$ROOT uses too much memory

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am preforming an aggregation query in mongo like so:

```
db.getCollection('snapshots').aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'user_id' : ObjectId("999999") } },
    { '$sort': { 'timestamp': -1 } },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$code',
            'docId': { '$first' : '$_id' },
        }
    },
    { '$skip': 0 },
    { '$limit': 10 },
]);
```

You can see I am sorting documents by "timestamp" descending, then grouping by "code", and getting the first document.

So one document per code, being the latest document. But in the end I need the whole original documents.

I saw that I can add a $$ROOT step to my aggregation pipeline in order to get the original documents, but it appears to use a **LOT** of memory. For example:

```
 '$group': {
            '_id' : '$ig_ad_code',
            'docId': { '$first' : '$_id' },
            'doc': { '$first' : '$$ROOT' },
        }
```

I guess that is because Mongo is retrieving the entire doc for every single document that enters the aggregation pipeline, and not just the 10x docs which I am asking for. I have ~5 million records, so I need to keep my pipeline stages lean.

My current thinking is to get my 10x document IDs from the above step, and feed them into a simple "find()" step. Is this the only option? Is there another pipeline that can retrieve documents based on a field from a previous aggregation step?

Thanks!

Comment: is your `timestamp` field indexed? what about the performance for `'docId': { '$first' : '$_id' }` without `$$ROOT`?

Comment: timestamp is indexed. performance without $$ROOT is fine,  with $$ROOT I get the error `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.`. And obviously I do not want to use disk unless I absolutely must; nor should I need to, after all I only want 10 docs.

Comment: as far as i can see, the only way is like you said. get the ids from aggregation and give its array to a `find` call.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a $project step at the end of the aggregation pipeline? Can $project be used to add a field whose value is an entire document (i.e. the result of a query)?

Comment: I dont think so. `$project` will only limit/change name of fields or structure. Instead of `$$ROOT` just try putting individual fields (only those you really need) like you did for `docId`